# extending factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I found good solution, with factory_girl extension here:
[Using factory_girl in Rails with associations that have unique constraints. Getting duplicate errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015473/using-factory-girl-in-rails-with-associations-that-have-unique-constraints-getti)

And now, how can I extend all my factories with same lambda/function with shared context over all factories?